# Azure виртуальная машина Centos 7 + apache + php + mysql нет внешнего подключения

Tags: php, apache, centos, azure

Здравствуйте.
Впервые занялся azure.
Установил виртуальную машину, которая без приставки "классическая"

развернул на ней Centos 7
Создал  группу безопасности и открыл порты входящие: 80 и некоторые другие

На centos установил php 7, httpd, mysql

все службы запускаются нормально, но я не могу зайти на сайт, скажем, с моего домашнего ПК. Что я делаю не так? 
Если с домашнего ПК по telnet'ту подключиться по 22 порту, все ок (оно и понятно, у азуры по умолчанию это единственный открытый порт), а вот по 80 порту подключение не идет.
Firewall отключен
Подскажите в каком направлении копать? Спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

Всё вы делаете так. Просто в Azure у виртуальных машин по умолчанию заблокированны все порты кроме RDP на машинах с Windows и SSH на машинах с Unix. Вам надо открыть порты не на самой машине, а на виртуальной сетевой карте через портал.

Если вы создавали машину через новый портал при помощи мэнеджера ресурсов, то открыть порты можно следующим образом: 
VM --> Network Interfaces --> Выбрать интерфейс через который будет осуществляться связь с внешним миром --> Network Security Group --> кликаете скорее всего на единственную группу --> Inbound security rules --> Add --> ну и добавляете все вам необходимые порты.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если вы создавали машины через старый портал, то там проще. VM --> Endpoints --> добавить нужные вам порты.

Comment: проблема в том, что у меня открыты порты